# How are different senses of the term 'harmonic' related to each other?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, functions, discrete-mathematics, trigonometry

I have been taught an harmonic wave in physics follows either a sine or cosine function.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function

Are there any Harmonic functions other than Sine and Cosine?

Why is the specific case of the Power Mean with P = -1 called an Harmonic Mean?

Are the variables somehow in a "good" relation between each other?

Sine, Cosine, Harmonic Functions, Harmonic Series, Harmonic Number, Harmonic Analysis, Harmonic Conjugates.

How are these exactly related? Why the term harmonic? Is any good relationship expressed?

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing the post title for clarity. Please check to ensure that the new title preserves the intended meaning (and adjust as appropriate if not).

Comment: @Travis Thank you very much. I earnestly appreciate your help. Do you think I should make it explicit that I mean senses in the context of Mathematics or the term "harmonic" in the context of Mathematics? Or is it reasonably safe tο assume I have been expressed in a straightforward way, absolutely clear and categorical,  leaving no leeway for questioning, confusion, doubt or vacillation? i.e I am stricly speaking of Mathematics alone since I am on a Q&A site for Mathematics? Am I risking having my question interpreted as too broad?

Comment: It's obvious from context that you mean mathematical senses. The scope of the problem seems fine to me. One could imagine a canonical answer no longer than a few paragraphs.

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos It seems "harmonic" is one of those words that has multiple meanings & uses that are sometimes only somewhat related to each other. For example, Wikipedia's "Harmonic (disambiguation)" at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_(disambiguation) shows there are many different uses of the term in various fields. Also, "Harmonic (mathematics)" at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_(mathematics) starts with "In mathematics, a number of concepts employ the word harmonic.", and then explains it further. I believe it gives a reasonable general answer to your question.